# Sharepoint - Weird language behavior after translation

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, sharepoint, modern-ui

I'm currently encountering a weird behavior of sharepoint in my current project.

The task is simple in its core:
We have a site collection, where we can create projects (projects are then subsites of the root site again). In v1 our product was only available in one language. In v2 we implement multilanguage.

When the new solutions are deployed, new project site are in the correct state.
The rootsite and older project sites are not.

I'm currently developing the update mechanism for the root and subsites.
And here somethin unexplainable (at least for me) happens:

1. Navigation:

   The navigation nodes have to be updated the following way

   ```
           foreach (CultureInfo culture in web.SupportedUICultures)
           {
               node.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture(culture, SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:" + key, resource, (uint)culture.LCID));
           }
           node.Update();
   ```

When I initiate the update while having german as my active display language, exactly 2 nodes are shown as $Resources:.... in german, but in english they are correct.
If i initiate the update while having english as my display language, all nodes are correct in both languages.

1. Listviewwebpart

   On one page we introduced a few listviewwebparts. I create them and customize the view of the webpart. When I start the update with english as language, everything works fine.
   The listview is completely translated both in german and english.

However, the moment i let the update run with german as active language, some fields are not translated. And here is the thing: Only in this exact listview! When i switch to the list, and check the fields, everything is ok!
I don't get it.

So in short:
     - Update with german: 2 Navigation don't get the resource value (just german, english works fine)
     - Update with english: Fields in listview not translated, but the fields are translated in its core.

Did someone ever encountered a behavior like this?
I tried changing the order in which the update works, but nothing changes.